# How to update the items in the vault?

Tags: corda

I'm currently training to become a corda developer.

I've created a simple corDapp which only has 1 participant, Here is the state I created:

```
@BelongsToContract(UserContract::class)
class UserState(val name: String,
                val age: Int,
                val address: String,
                val gender: GenderEnums,
                val node: Party,
                val status: StatusEnums,
                override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier,
                override val participants : List<Party>
) : LinearState
```

So when I run the corDapp, I get my desired output https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKA28.jpg

But what I want to do is to update the vault. I would, for example, like to update the address from "Pampanga" to "Manila", But I don't know where to start. All I know is that since States are immutable, you have to consume the state first.

I tried to create a flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class UpdateUserFlows(private val name :String,
                      private val age : Int,
                      private val address : String,
                      private val gender: GenderEnums,
                      private val status : StatusEnums,
                      private val counterParty: Party): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    private fun userStates(): UserState {
        return UserState(
                name = name,
                age = age,
                address = address,
                gender = gender,
                status = status,
                node = ourIdentity,
                linearId = UniqueIdentifier(),
                participants = listOf(ourIdentity, counterParty)
        )
    }

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val transaction: TransactionBuilder = transaction()
        val signedTransaction: SignedTransaction = verifyAndSign(transaction)
        val sessions: List<FlowSession> = (userStates().participants - ourIdentity).map { initiateFlow(it) }.toSet().toList()
        val transactionSignedByAllParties: SignedTransaction = collectSignature(signedTransaction, sessions)
        return recordTransaction(transactionSignedByAllParties, sessions)
    }

    private fun transaction(): TransactionBuilder {
        val notary: Party = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()
        val issueCommand = Command(UserContract.Commands.Issue(), userStates().participants.map { it.owningKey })
        val builder = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)
        builder.addOutputState(userStates(), UserContract.ID)
        builder.addCommand(issueCommand)
        return builder
    }

    private fun verifyAndSign(transaction: TransactionBuilder): SignedTransaction {
        transaction.verify(serviceHub)
        return serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transaction)
    }


    @Suspendable
    private fun collectSignature(
            transaction: SignedTransaction,
            sessions: List<FlowSession>
    ): SignedTransaction = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(transaction, sessions))

    @Suspendable
    private fun recordTransaction(transaction: SignedTransaction, sessions: List<FlowSession>): SignedTransaction =
            subFlow(FinalityFlow(transaction, sessions))
}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are right, states are immutable in Corda and to mimic an update you basically need to create a transaction where the input is your current version of the state (i.e. address = Pampanga), and the output would be a new instance of `UserState` which has the same `linearId` and other attribute values as the input, but a different address value (i.e. Manila).
- This way you are creating a new state (the output of the transaction), but because it will have the same `linearId` value; it would be as if you updated the input to become the output, this will allow you to see all the previous versions of a state by querying the vault by its `linearId`.
- You didn't share the code of your contract, but you need to add a new command (let's call it `Update`); and also you need to add the verification rules that apply to it.
- Inside your flow, you'd use that command (instead of `Issue`).